npm ERR! code 126 - Exec format error when installing node-sass
I'm encountering an issue while trying to install node-sass in my project. Whenever I run npm install, I receive the following error:
npm ERR! code 126
npm ERR! path C:\Users\hix\Documents\GitHub\feedht\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command bash -c node scripts/install.js
npm ERR! /bin/bash: line 1: /usr/bin/node: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

It seems to be related to an Exec format error, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. I've checked the permissions and they seem to be fine. What might be causing this error and how to fix it?

Why are you trying to install it at all? It's deprecated.

After cloning my project from GitHub, I want to set up my Ionic project.
